# Use xmlstarlet to search for an XPATH and update a parent element

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I am new to xmlstarlet. I have the following xml file (parts have been deleted for clarity) which is actually a KML file from Google My Maps:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <Folder>
      <name>Property</name>
      <Placemark>
        <name>kml_1</name>
        <styleUrl>#poly-000000-1200-77</styleUrl>
        <ExtendedData>
          <Data name="housenumber">
            <value>222</value>
          </Data>
          <Data name="address">
            <value>222 MAIN STREET HAPPYTOWN</value>
          </Data>
        </ExtendedData>
      </Placemark>
    </Folder>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

I want to use xmlstarlet to find `"//_:kml/_:Document/_:Folder[_:name='Property']/_:Placemark/_:ExtendedData/_:Data/_:value='222 MAIN STREET HAPPYTOWN'"` and then update the `styleUrl` element from `#poly-000000-1200-77` to `#poly-colour01`.

The XML file contains multiple `Folder` and `Placemark` elements and I need to be specific as to which one I update.

Is that possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you insert `_:` everywhere in your XPATH, since your XML file uses the default namespace? Do I miss something?

Comment: Probably because I am learning and not sure of the best way to construct an XPATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the following is going to be long and convoluted mainly because of having to deal with namespaces, but try it on your actual xml and see if it works:

```
xml  
ed  
-N x="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" 
-u  '//x:Document/x:Folder[x:name="Property"]/x:Placemark[x:ExtendedData//x:Data[@name="address"]/x:value="222 MAIN STREET HAPPYTOWN"]/x:styleUrl'  
-v "#poly-colour01"  
file.xml
```